# How to ignore shutdown of windows?

Tags: windows

There is alot of people using my computer. TOLD them not to shutdown my PC but they keep turning it off by mistake. I want when pressing shutdown via windows to turn off display or just ignoring the shutdown command. Is this possible?

Comment: You can install classic start menu, which allows you to set the default power action. There is still a menu for full shut down, but its an extra click. In conjunction with the answer for power options, this might be the nicest way to do this. The other answer is forcefully stopping people from shutting down. So if you don't give them an easy alternative, they may leave the pc on.

Comment: If they have physical access then a hard shutdown is always possible (long press of power button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the "Shut down the system" privilege from the `Users` group via "Local Security Policy" `secpol.msc` → "Local Policies" → "User Rights Assignment".

Comment: First time knowing that. Thank you, Now I am going to make another user.

Comment: In addition having this also:
Open Control Panel > Click on System and Security.

Under "Power Options" click the Change what the power buttons do link. Using the drop-down menu for "When I press the power button"

select the action you want: Do nothing. Sleep. Hibernate. Shut down. Turn off the display. Click the Save changes button at the bottom of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Open Control Panel > Click on System and Security.

Under "Power Options" click the Change what the power buttons do link.
Using the drop-down menu for "When I press the power button"

select the action you want:
Do nothing.
Sleep.
Hibernate.
Shut down.
Turn off the display.
Click the Save changes button at the bottom of the window.